# Cursor description text box

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I have searched a lot and couldn't found the approach to create the small text box right next to the cursor, when doing hover over on HTML object.

[Example http://guyzyl.org/wp/Picture1.png](http://guyzyl.org/wp/Picture1.png)

You can see cursor is not visible in this example, but the text box appears on hover over. I would like to create some thing similar.

Example is taken from the Facebook.

Thanks for the help

Comment: That would usually be done using JavaScript. It's called a 'tooltip'. Something like this: http://jquery.bassistance.de/

Comment: first of all, thanks for the quick response, that is what i was looking for. can you tell me how i create a very simple one? (using javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tooltips can be obtained on  tags adding the `title` attribute to them, e.g.:

```
<a href="#" title="my tooltip">my link</a>
```

fancier looking tooltips can be obtained using javascript but the above is the correct semantic option (many tooltip plugins expect it to be in your code anyway)

Comment: you should use the "alt" attribute on a img element

Comment: @Luca Wrong. You can use the title attribute as well as the alt attribute for a tooltip when hovering over an image.

Comment: @Sam you can use title on a image because your browser is built to support it, but it's not W3C compliant: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img#HTML_Attributes - quote: "ALT: Gives the fallback content for the image." I didn't say he can't use title on img - browsers are built to support it. blame IE<8 about having tooltips on img tags - those versions used to display the alt content as a tooltip http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200908/ie_8_does_not_display_alt_text_in_a_tooltip/

Comment: So explain why this code snippet validates -> http://jsfiddle.net/Kqb8r/2/ . You need to retype the closing html tag for some reason)

Comment: perhaps I didn't write both the validator and the w3c specs - I'm referring to the w3c specs and there is no mention of a title attribute in there as you can see by yourself, and to reiterate - I didn't ever say he can't use the title attribute - I only suggested he should use the alt attribute for the sake of having it. Constructive criticism, not destructive, please - we are not here to argue or find who's the coolest guy ;)

Comment: to make my answer clearer, I should have said that he can use title, but should ALSO have alt, my bad if I didn't express myself the right way!

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
    <img title="my tooltip" src="" alt=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called tooltip. write like this for example:

```
<div class="parent">
 <p>create group</p>
 <div class="tooltip">tooltip</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip{
 display:none;
}
.parent:hover .tooltip{display:block;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/zDLzF/

Comment: that's not semantically valid, not accessible (screenreaders) and  need further styling to look like a tooltip...

Comment: who said it's not semantically.there are several types of tooltip.

Comment: you are adding text content to a element that is extraneous to the one that it should be related to. This makes no sense to a screen reader that will also not read it as you are setting display:none; to it. Basically what you are doing is not a tooltip at all, it just "look like" on a browser. Semantically valid tooltips are to be in the title attribute of an <a> tag.
http://aninnovativeweb.tumblr.com/post/820491172/semantic-tooltips-with-pure-css3-and-html5

Comment: to further clarify - a screen reader will be able to "understand" a title attribute but has no way to understand that your div class="tooltip" behaves the same way. it's just plain text in there for it. The reason behind using the correct semantic tags for your code is a very good practise in terms of accessibility - we cannot just think like "it looks like the way I want" - as we are not producing web code for web browsers and people without disabilities only.

Comment: @Luca First OP not define there is any title or something & second if you see the image is not default title tooltip.

Comment: That's a very sleek solution. Pretty cool. Somehow it breaks in IE8, but I didn't do further testing, just copied the code from your link.

Comment: @sandeep what you say is true but I believe when writing code we should keep in mind that it should work in any situation, that to me means with no css, with no js, on a screen reader, when using a keyboard rather than a mouse to browse - basically, accessibility. Once this is in place, there can be more fanciness - progressive enhancement - so you can get the tooltip the fancy way it looks on his example, and your site will still be accessible by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

There are many fancy tooltips available. The Simplest jQuery Tooltip Ever - http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery